# Spring Security AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter Extension Losing Instance Variable Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Once again, I'm hoping I'm doing something really dumb here. :)

I have an extension of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` in my Spring Security implementation, and in that extension, in the `attemptAuthentication` method, I access the passed-in `HttpServletRequest` object and pull out a header value, which I store in an instance variable.

I'm noticing that, sometimes, during a call to another custom method in my project, the value of that instance variable is being `null`'d out.  It isn't consistent, though.

I can't see any code in my custom method that would be responsible for overwriting the variable, so, I'm trying to narrow things down.  I'm hoping it's not something like thread safety that I've overlooked, or some kind of race condition.

Has anyone come across anything like this before?

I'm using **Spring 4.1.1** and **Spring Security 3.2.5**.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container will only create a single instance of the filter, so having any mutable instance variables is not thread safe. Any concurrent request can cause inconsistent state for your instance variable. You should look into [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).

In response to comment:

It's not so much that you have to use HttpSession, just don't use instance variables in a servlet/filter as they are not thread safe. If you need to maintain state, and you don't want to use sessions, then AFAIK, you'll need to pass client information with every request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The security is for some REST services, and to help with performance, we've disabled sessions. Are there any other solutions short of enabling sessions?

Comment: Yeah I sussed that out and am working on a quick change to avoid the instance variables, which I believe I don't actually need.  Thanks for the sounding board and the suggestions!